# Rails 500 No Stack Trace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I'll start by admitting that I am very new to Rails. Which is unfortunate since I've been tasked with maintaining a Rails app.

I have a Rails App that uses Nginx and Passenger backed by postgres running on an EC2 with Ubuntu. I deleted a row in one of the db tables which caused one of the pages to 500. I have enabled the error log in the nginx config (and restarted it) but it doesn't seem to be outputting anything. Where can I find the stack trace for the Rails app?

Comment: Errors from Rails are outputted by Rails, not by nginx. Find the Rails app root and in there should be a `log` folder. This is the standard Rails app folder structure.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-directory-structure.htm

Comment: You're absolutely right. I had checked there once before and it wasn't there BUT nginx was actually using another directory for the root. So I've been working in the wrong directory. Doh! Thanks for your response. I'll mark it as the answer if you post it.